# gui control that shows current battery level windows mobile C#

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, controls, power-management

I'm looking for a control for Visual Studio that can display the current battery life of windows mobile device. Has anyone come across this before?

Do you know if we can create such a control by ourselves? If so, how?

Comment: Since you're mentioning C#, do you mean Windows Phone 7 and not Windows Mobile?

Comment: Won't progressbar do? Or are you looking for control, that will obtain battery state itself?

Comment: There is an API to get the batterylevel(s), so it's easy to DIY. Just don't expect it to be very accurate.

Comment: @pickypg: I mean Windows Mobile..
@torvin: I'm not sure if a progress bar will do the job.. I'll try.. 
I'm look for some control that shows the battery life on screen, so if the battery life is 50%, it should have half the control shaded or coloured and half empty.. Is there a special control to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Create 5 battery icons:

1. Battery Full
2. Battery High
3. Battery Medium
4. Battery Low
5. Battery Very Low

using Microsoft.WindowsMobile.Status;

```
private void UpdateBatteryIcon()
{
    var batteryLevel = SystemState.PowerBatteryStrength;
    var isOnCharge = IsOnCharge(SystemState.PowerBatteryState);
    pictBattery.Image = GetBatteryIcon(batteryLevel, isOnCharge);
}
private static Bitmap GetBatteryIcon(BatteryLevel batteryState, bool isCharging)
{
    if (isCharging)
    {
        return Icons.BatteryChargingHorizontal;
    }
    if (batteryState == BatteryLevel.VeryLow)
    {
        return Icons.BatteryVeryLowHorizontal;
    }
    if (batteryState == BatteryLevel.Low)
    {
        return Icons.BatteryLowHorizontal;
    }
    if (batteryState == BatteryLevel.Medium)
    {
        return Icons.BatteryMediumHorizontal;
    }
    if (batteryState == BatteryLevel.High)
    {
        return Icons.BatteryHighHorizontal;
    }
    return Icons.BatteryFullHorizontal;
}
```